# Web scraping currency exchange after user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the currency exchange value after the user inputs the value. Worldremit.com has a categorical exchange rate, for example, Euro to INR,  € 0-500 has one exchange rate, and € 500-1000 has one exchange rate.

Requirement: Keep track of exchange rate, send an email when exchange rates reach a specific value (I have plans to run the python code from google server later on)

URL: https://www.worldremit.com/en?selectfrom=de&ds_rl=1262314&ds_rl=1262326&ds_rl=1262314&gclid=CjwKCAiA_omPBhBBEiwAcg7smfiUbgpbl_SRSOvS6QqjrqZ9zNFgx22VvTVJrdG0ddnQjeSZ0ve05RoCEskQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&transfer=bnk&selectto=in&amountfrom=1001.00&currencyto=inr&currencyfrom=eur

Python code

```
import requests
from icecream import ic
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.worldremit.com/en?selectfrom=de&ds_rl=1262314&ds_rl=1262326&ds_rl=1262314&gclid=CjwKCAiA_omPBhBBEiwAcg7smfiUbgpbl_SRSOvS6QqjrqZ9zNFgx22VvTVJrdG0ddnQjeSZ0ve05RoCEskQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&transfer=bnk&selectto=in&amountfrom=100.00&currencyto=inr&currencyfrom=eur"


headers = {"User-Agent" : <enter/your/user/agent/here>}

# to get the page from a URL with a header
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

# to get the content from a page and parse it use beatifulsoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'receive'}).find('div', {'class':'MuiInputBase-root-300 MuiInputBase-colorSecondary-306 jss292'})

#print
ic(div)
```

output: [image: Output]

Problem: I only see the output as 100. How to get the value after the user inputs a specific value say €1000.

my output is always 100 irrespective of the input although website inspection shows correctly.

[image]